# php array of images in reverse order

Tags: php, arrays, advanced-custom-fields

So far I have been able to display images using the explode function and echo images individually. The two things I would like to do are- Display an array of images weather it's 5 or 50. Then display these images in reverse order, as the feature image is always last.

I have tried quiet a few other options on the forums, but not able to translate into this code. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

$string = get_field( 'slider' );
$split = explode ( '|', $string );
echo "<li><img src='{$split[0]}' /></li>";
echo "<li><img src='{$split[1]}' /></li>";
echo "<li><img src='{$split[2]}' /></li>";
echo "<li><img src='{$split[3]}' /></li>";

?>
```

Comment: since `$split` can hold many elements, you cant just hardcode them each, just like you stated (it may contain 5, or 50, or 500). you just need a loop for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [array_reverse()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) method of PHP to reverse the order of the array. And loop through it using [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to display all the images from the array as shown below.

```
$string = get_field( 'slider' );
$split = explode ( '|', $string );

$split = array_reverse($split);

foreach($split as $img){
  echo "<li><img src='{$img}' /></li>";
}
```

Comment: Jay this works perfectly, and loops over 4 million linked images to my site.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = get_field( 'slider' );

$split = explode ( '|', $string );

$reversed = array_reverse($split);
```

Here, you will get array in reversed order.
Now you can **loop** this array and display images in reverse order.

For more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Thanks @subashbasnet8 I have used this code with the loop below.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use foreach loop on the explode result

```
$string = get_field( 'slider' );
$split = explode( '|', $string );
foreach(array_reverse($split) as $src) {
  echo "<li><img src='$src' /></li>";
}
```